# Уникальный id при дублировнии(клонировнии) объекта в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

В своём проекте на Unity3d пытаюсь вынести в `ScriptableObject` важные данные об объектах на сцене.

Объекты однотипные, но информация **о каждом экземпляре в сцене** должна храниться в `List<T>` в экземпляре `SceneData : ScriptableObject`. К этой информации объект сцены будет обращается в процессе игры.

Например есть класс с данными:

```
public class PersonData
{
    long id;
    string firstName;
    Gender gender;
    float cash;
}
```

Он сохраняется в `List<PersonData>` `ScriptableObject` и ссылка на экземпляр PersonData будет импортироваться в класс PersonView:

```
public class PersonView : MonoBehaviour
{
    long id;
    PersonData data;
}
```

Ссылка на `PersonData` будет добавятся `PersonView` при открытии сцены в редакторе и после загрузки сцены в игре. Загрузка сцены будет из `assetBundle`, скачиваемого через интернет, поэтому связывание данных должно быть по `id`, который будет генерироваться при добавлении объекта `PersonView` на сцену в редакторе, в методе `OnEnable`:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(PersonView))]
public class PersonViewEditor : Editor
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
       var pv = this.target as PersonView;
       if(pv.id == 0)
       {
           pv.data = new PersonData();
           pv.data = pv.id = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
           EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
       }
    }
}
```

При сохранении сцены, данные из `PersonView` сохраняются в `PersonData`.

**Проблема:** при дублировании объекта(`Ctrl+d`), `id` старого объекта **копируется** в новый, а мне нужно чтобы она **создавалась заново**.

Единственный вариант, который я вижу: это в методе OnEnable() искать дубликаты, и если объект с таким же `id` присутствует на сцене, генерировать новый `id` и `PersonData`:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(PersonView))]
public class PersonViewEditor : Editor
{
    PersonView pv;
    void OnEnable()
    {
       pv = this.target as PersonView;
       
       if(pv.id == 0) { SetNewId(); return; }
       else {
           var views = FindObjectsOfType<PersonView>()
           foreach(var view in views)
           {
              if(pv.id == view.id) { SetNewId(); return; }
           }
       }
    }

    private void SetNewId()
    {
        pv.data = new PersonData();
        pv.data = pv.id = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял персоны записывают в `SceneData` свои дефолтные значения выставленные в инспекторе если их там нет или читают если они там уже есть. Все персоны неповторимы и загвоздка в том что-бы понять какие данные для какой персоны.

Вообще данные всегда разделяют на константы и  изменяемые чтобы была возможность сохранять только изменяемые. То есть `firstName` и `gender` не меняются в отличие от `cash` которые нужно сохранять.

```
[Serializable]
public struct PersonData
{
    public PersonConstants Constants;
    public PersonalProperties Properties;
}

[Serializable]
public struct PersonConstants
{
    public string FirstName;
    public Gender Gender;
}

[Serializable]
public struct PersonalProperties
{
    public float Cash;
}
```

Сохранять нужно будить только `PersonalProperties` в обертке с неким `id` (`int` или `string`) в некой сущности с массивом через `JsonUtility`, а json хранить в `PlayerPrefs` или на сервере. В сохранении `PersonConstants` никакого смысла нет.

```
[Serializable]
public struct PersonalPropertiesSaveArray
{
    public PersonalPropertiesSave[] Persons;
}

[Serializable]
public struct PersonalPropertiesSave
{
    public string ID;
    public PersonalProperties Properties;
}
```

---

```
PersonalPropertiesSaveArray save;
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(save);

PersonalPropertiesSaveArray load;
load = JsonUtility.FromJson<PersonalPropertiesSaveArray>(json);
```

Касаемо идентификации кто есть кто. Я не понял почему сущность называется `SceneData`, вроде к конкретной сцене это не привязано, скорее `PersonalDataProvider`. В каждой сцене должен быть объект имеющий ссылки на всех персон на сцене, некий `ScenePersonals`. Именно он и отвечает за идентификацию.

```
public class PersonalDataProvider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PersonalDataProvider _provider;
    [SerializeField] private Personal[] _personals;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        Load();
    }
    
    private void OnDisable ()
    {
        Save();
    }

    private void Load ()
    {
        _provider.Load();
        for (int i = 0; i < _personals.Length; i++)
        {
            string id = GetID(i);
            if (_provider.HasPersonal(id))
                _personals[i].Data.Properys = _provider.GetPropertys(id);
        }
    }

    private void Save ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _personals.Length; i++)
        {
            string id = GetID(i);
            // по id провайдер сам разберется это новые данные которые
            // нужно добавить в текущий справочник или изменить имеющиеся 
            _provider.SetPropertys(id, _personals[i].Data.Properys);
        }
        _provider.Save();

    }

    private string GetID (int index)
    {
        // простой вариант, имя сцены + индекс в списке
        return gameObject.scene.name+index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. И в особенности за ту часть где речь идёт от том что константы имеет смысл хранить отдельно, хотя gender в наше время давно перестал быть чем то постоянным =)

Comment: Если я правильно понял вы предлагаете хранить в объекте сцены `ScenePersonals` ссылки на объекты `Personal : MonoBehaviour`, отвечающие за представление. И (условно) по индексам определять `id` соответствующих `Properys`

Comment: Ссылки на объекты в сцене можно сохранять в список `List<Personal>` и проверять наличие в этом списке в методе `OnEnable()` кастомного редактора для `Personal`. 
В принципе такая концепция решает проблему дубликатов(ссылки на сами объекты при клонировании получаются уникальные и в пределах сцены остаются актуальными). Жаль Unity не сериализует Dictionary. Тогда было бы вообще замечательно.

Comment: Да сериализация `Dictionary` это было бы здорово. Меня единственноч что бесит это привязанность к индексу массива. То есть расширять можно, а при удалении нужно оставлять null и добавлять сверху... херня. Есть еще вариант каждую дату делать `ScriptableObject`. `InstanceId` объектов сцены каждый раз меняется, а у ассетов остается.

Comment: Есть два путя: не безопасный, но быстрый - отказаться от `id` и в `ScriptableObject` и в `ScenePersonals` хранить простые списки и там и там обращаться по индексу в списке. Либо: в `Personal : MonoBehaviour` хранить копию сгенерированного `id`.